# Been learning mongodb and node. Next step I want to learn is how to authenticate users. As a beginner, what all do I have to keep in mind for this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

So far I have made a small app where you can write notes and such.  A title, message, and image.

Now, I am trying to learn how to do a user authentication so that the only way to post will be after signing in to the app.

I have been looking online, but many of the concepts are quite difficult to understand.  I already have a user model, so what all things do I have to keep in mind to authenticate the user?  How do you pass the username and password for example (plain text is bad right?)?   Etc.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to start with a pre-configured template like [MEAN](http://mean.io/) stack - where you can lean by example.